# Comparing elements in my array to find pairs, but can't figure out what to do when it finds two pairs

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to compare elements in a single array to pull out any pairs, three of a kind, four of a kind, or five of a kind... I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do so. I also have to print out the number in which is in a pair, three of a kind, etc... This is what I have so far. Any clues or ideas?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DieGame3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Die die1 = new Die(6);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the pairing game!");

        System.out.print("The 5 rolled dice: ");
        int[] numbers = new int[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            die1.roll();
            numbers[i] = die1.getValue();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
        findPairs(numbers);
    }
    public static int[] findPairs(int[] d1) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < d1.length; i++) {
            for (int k = i + 1; k < d1.length; k++) {
                if (d1[i] == d1[k]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
            if(count == 1)
                System.out.println("You've got " + count + " pair.");
            else
                System.out.println("You've got " + count + " of a kind.");
        return d1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I assume your number is too high because you are counting pairs twice with the code above? You must remove one of the pairs or else each pair will be counted double

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by "I am trying to compare elements in a single array to pull out any pairs, three of a kind, four of a kind, or five of a kind...".  For example, should a pair be detected in {1, 2, 3, 4, 1}?  Or should only adjacent ("in a row") values be counted?  For example, {2, 3, 1, 1, 4}.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to somehow keep track of which elements in the array have already been counted. The simplest method is to use a `boolean` array of the same length, and set it to true when you find a matching element.

```
public static void findPairs(int[] d1) {  
  boolean[] seen = new boolean[d1.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < d1.length-1; i++) {
    if(!seen[i])
    {
      int count = 1;
      for (int k = i + 1; k < d1.length; k++) {
          if (d1[i] == d1[k]) {
            seen[k] = true;
            count++;
          }
      }
      if(count > 1)
        System.out.printf("%d %ds\n", count, d1[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

When called with input `[5, 5, 3, 3, 3]` this prints

```
2 5s
3 3s
```

Comment: Wow, something so simple! I tend to overthink things way too much. Thank you so much! I hope you have a great day :D